# Closed form for the sum $\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^d} \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{k}\|^{\alpha}_2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I am wondering if there is a closed form for

\begin{align*}\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^d \setminus \{0\}}  \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{k}\|^{\alpha}_2},
\end{align*}

where $d$ is a finite integer, $\alpha>2$ and the norm is l2 norm. I know this can be bounded by using $\zeta(\alpha/2)$ since
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{k_1^2+...+k_d^2}\leq\frac{1}{d}(\frac{1}{k_1^2}+...+\frac{1}{k_d^2}).
\end{align*}

Further I am interested in the convergence speed of the following finite sum to the given one above: 
\begin{align*}S_M=\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^d, \|\boldsymbol{k}\|_2\leq M}  \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{k}\|^{\alpha}_2},
\end{align*}　
and I am guessing the convergence rate is something like
\begin{align*}|\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^d}  \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{k}\|^{\alpha}_2}-S_M|\to O(M^{-\alpha}).\end{align*}
Can anyone help with this?

I would not be surprised if this has already been studied but I cannot find any reference or appropriate words to search. 
Thanks!

Comment: Reading up on the [Epstein zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analytic_Eisenstein_series#Epstein_zeta_function) will give some related considerations.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K Hi, take a look at my answer and feel free to improve

Comment: @reuns At first glance, I don't quite spot your closed form solution. Also, I think you flipped one sign before the s in the argument of the function.

Comment: Did you manage to find the convergence rate of $|\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^d}  \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{k}\|^{\alpha}_2}-S_M|$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a closed-form for $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d \setminus \{0\}} \|k\|^{-2m}$.

The derivation is quite long, do you know the theory of the Riemann zeta function ?

Let $$\Theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x} \qquad \Theta(x)^d = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d} e^{-\pi \|k\|^2 x}, \qquad \mathfrak{Z}_d(s)=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d \setminus \{0\}} \|k\|^{-s}$$
Then $\Lambda_d(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} (\Theta(x)^d-1) dx = \pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\mathfrak{Z}_d(s)$.
The poisson summation formula yields $\Theta(x) = x^{-1/2} \Theta(1/x)$ from which we obtain $$\Lambda_d(s) = \frac{1}{s-d}-\frac{1}{-s}+\int_1^\infty (x^{s/2-1}+x^{(d-s)/2})(\Theta(x)^d-1)dx= \Lambda_d(d-s) $$ and $\Theta(x) = \sum_{m=-1}^{M-1} c_m x^{m/2}+ \mathcal{O}(x^{M/2})$,

which means $\Lambda(s)-\int_0^1 x^{s/2-1}\sum_{m=-1}^{M-1} c_m x^{m/2}  dx=\Lambda(s)-\sum_{m=-1}^{M-1} c_m \frac{2}{s+m}$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > -M$.

And the same holds with $\Theta(x)^d = (\sum_{m=-1}^{M-1} c_m x^{m/2}+ \mathcal{O}(x^{M/2}))^d=\sum_{m=-d}^{M-d} c_m(d) x^{m/2}+\mathcal{O}(x^{(M-d)/2}$.

Whence $\mathfrak{Z}_d(-2m) = \lim_{s\to -2m} \frac{\pi^{m}}{\Gamma(s/2)}\Lambda_d(s) = \lim_{s\to -2m} \frac{\pi^{m}}{\Gamma(s/2)}\sum_{m=-1}^{M-1} c_m(d) \frac{2}{s+m} = \pi^m \frac{m!}{(-1)^m}c_{2m}(d)$

Finally we use the same method to evaluate from $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-2}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$ that $\zeta(-m) = (-1)^m\frac{B_{m+1}}{m+1}$ where $\frac{x}{e^x-1}= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{B_m}{m!} x^m$

And from $\mathfrak{Z}_1(s) = 2 \zeta(s)$ we evaluate the $c_{m}$ and hence the $c_{m}(d)$ and $\mathfrak{Z}_d(-2m)$ and $\mathfrak{Z}_d(d+2m)$.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer. I know the Riemann Zeta function but not the theory and details. I was trying to follow your discussion, but not so easy for me. As far as I can see, $\mathfrak{Z}_d(2+2m)$ can be derived from $\mathfrak{Z}_d(-2m)$ and the coefficients $c_{m}(d)$ can be somehow calculated recursively?  Also, would you have any idea  about the convergence speed $|\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^d}  \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{k}\|^{\alpha}_2}-S_M|$ in the original question?

Comment: I meant $\mathfrak{Z}_d(d+2m)$, not $\mathfrak{Z}_d(2+2m)$. Also your $c_m$ and $c_m(d)$ are different, right? If it is easier to tell some references, please let me know.

Comment: @2019ys The convergence speed is the same for $\int_{(1,\infty)^d} \|x\|^{-a} dx$. I'm not sure of my conclusion, but for sure any special value of $\mathfrak{Z}_d(s)$ is obtained the way I said