# How to regularize $\sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2}' \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} $?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, regularization

I would like to evaluate the Dedekind zeta function of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ at $\frac{1}{2}$.  Naively the Dekind zeta function should be

$$ \zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]} (s) = \sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2}' \frac{1}{(a^2 + b^2)^s} $$

Hopefully I have indexed the ideals of $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]$ correctly.  Then to make matter worse, I am going to evluate at $s = \frac{1}{2}$:

$$ \zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]} (\frac{1}{2}) = \sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2}' \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} $$

This is a divergent series, but all is not lost.  Since if we define $\zeta(s)$ for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 2$ then we could try to analytic continue to the rest of $\mathbb{C}$.  (Does this series converge for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$ ?)

---

The strategy I am seeing, uses Fermat little Theorem to express $\zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(s)$ in terms of $\zeta(s)$ and $L(s, \chi_4)$.  In that case, I'd like to see how to regularize:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(\frac{1}{2}) &"="& 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \dots \\
L(\frac{1}{2}, \chi_4) &"="&  1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} - \dots  
\end{eqnarray*}

I think the second one already has a value without quotation marks, but the first one we need to subtract out the infinite part, $2\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $\zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(s) = 4 \zeta(s) L(s,\chi_4)$ ? (usually by looking at the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and proving it is a PID, ie. [Fermat's two square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares))

Answer (score 1):

$$L(s) = \zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(s)=\sum_{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}'\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^s}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{r_2(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4\sum_{d\mid n}\chi_4(d)}{n^s} $$
leads to
$$ L(s) = 4\cdot L(\chi_4,s)\cdot\zeta(s) $$
where $\chi_4$ is the non-principal Dirichlet's character $\!\!\pmod{4}$. It follows that the $\zeta$-regularization of $\sum_{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}'\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^s}$ at $s=\frac{1}{2}$ equals
$$ 4\,\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\approx -3.90026492. $$
The average value of $r_2(n)$ is $\pi$ by Gauss circle problem, hence $\sum_{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}'\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^s}$ is convergent for any $s:\text{Re}(s)>1$, by summation by parts.

Comment: @reuns: I do not get it: what here needs more work? The series defining $L(\chi_4,s)$ is already convergent at $s=\frac{1}{2}$, and the series defining $L(s)$ is convergent over $\text{Re}(s)>1$ since Gauss circle problem ensures $\sum_{n=1}^{N} r_2(n) = \pi N + O(\sqrt{N})$.

Comment: I meant my [answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556970/closed-form-for-the-sum-sum-boldsymbolk-in-mathbbzd-frac1-bolds/2557599#2557599) needs more work (for which $s,d$ does $\mathfrak{Z}_d(s) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^d}' \|m\|^{-s}$ have a closed-form, knowing it is modular of weight $d/2$ and has a functional equation)

Comment: Also is the remainder $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ term as hard to estimate as 
 the [Dirichlet divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem) ? Under the Lindelof hypothesis for $\zeta(s),L(s,\chi_4)$ we should have something like $\sum_{n=1}^{N} r_2(n) = \pi N + O(N^{1/4+\epsilon})$.

Comment: @reuns: actually the $O(\sqrt{N})$ term is simply derived from a geometric argument and it is far from being optimal. Voronoi showed (through Bessel functions) $\sum_{n=1}^{N}r_2(n) = \pi N+O(N^{1/3})$ and further refinements came later.

Comment: Yes [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem#Generalisations) explains it quite well. In fact $\mathfrak{Z}_2(2s) = 4 \zeta(s) L(s,\chi_4)$ doesn't have a closed-form at any positive integers because it vanishes at every negative integers ?